# How to integrate the above expression? Please help me out?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int [e^{x}/(1+e^{x^{2}})]dx$$. I can easily integrate $$\int [e^{x}/(1+e^{x})]dx$$. But I am facing problem to integrate this expression. Please help me out. To integrate $e^{x}/(1+e^{x})$ we have to substitute $e^{x}=u$ and then we will get $e^{x}dx=du$. So, the final result of the integration will be $ln|1+e^{x}|+C$.That is easy, but this integration is really very much difficult. Please help.

Comment: Wolfram says it has no antiderivative in terms of the functions it uses, which includes things like hypergeomterics.

Comment: The real question is why you would expect there to be a closed form.

Comment: No, I am also not sure. Maybe there is not any closed form for this integration.

Comment: Can you use a series? One method is to set up a geometric series andbintegrate term nmby term; you can arrangecto get an infinite series of error functions. If this is suitable I will expand to an answer.

Comment: What's the context to this problem? Where are you getting $\int {e^x\over{1+e^{x^2}}} \, dx$ from?

Comment: @EmmaBellHelium, it is only the question.

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$\frac{1}{1+e^{x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n e^{-(n+1) x^2}$$
$$\int\frac{e^x}{1+e^{x^2}}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int e^{x-(n+1) x^2}\,dx$$ Complete the square and integrate
$$I_n= \int e^{x-(n+1) x^2}\,dx=\frac 12  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n+1}}\,\,e^{\frac{1}{4 (n+1)}}\,\,\text{erf}\left(\frac{2 (n+1) x-1}{2 \sqrt{n+1}}\right)$$

The problem is that, for almost any range of integration, the convergence will be very slow.

For example, for the integral between $0$ and $1$

$$\left| \frac{I_{n+1}}{I_n}\right|\sim 1-\frac 3{2n}$$

**Edit**

For the computation of
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^x}{1+e^{x^2}}\,dx$$

since it is an alternating series, if you want to know the number of terms $n$ to be added for a given accuracy, you need to solve for $n$
$$\frac{1}{2}  \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n+2}}\,\,e^{\frac{1}{4 (n+2)}}\, \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{n+2}}\right)\right) \leq 10^{-k}$$
Taking the logarithm of the lhs and using series, we have
$$\log(\text{lhs})=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{4 n}{\pi }\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi } }+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ leading to
$$n\sim \frac{1}{\pi \,\, W\left(\frac{2 }{\pi }10^{-k}\right)^2}\sim \frac \pi 4 10^{2k}$$

It could be hard to find a slower convergence :   for $k=3$, you would need to add $786398$ terms $\large (\text{!!})$.

Computing the partial sums
$$S_k=\sum_{n=0}^{10^k} (-1)^n\, I_n$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & S_k \\
 1 & 1.31058 \\
 2 & 1.20169 \\
 3 & 1.16938 \\
 4 & 1.15958 \\
 5 & 1.15653 \\
 6 & 1.15557 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty & 1.15513 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$